# Using piecewise function in objective function in Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I am trying to use a piecewise linear function from Pyomo in my objective function. This piecewise linear function is actually interpolating an array of values called `macc`, having 401 values (macc[i], i from 0 to 400). You can see the values of macc in the picture attached

[image]

My objective function is looking for the value `i` for which `macc[i]` respect the constraints. To do that I interpolate the array macc to have a continuous function f. See below:

```
c = np.arange(401)
f = pyopiecewise.piecewise(c,macc,validate=False)
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

#Declare variable
model.x = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals, bounds=(5,395), initialize = cp0)

#Declare parameters
model.s = pyo.Param(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals,initialize=s0)
model.b = pyo.Param(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals,initialize=b0)
model.tnac = pyo.Param(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals,initialize=tnac0)

#Objective function
def objective_(m):
    ab = f(m.x)

    e = m.b - ab

    return (e * m.x)

#Constraints
def constraint1(m):

    ab = f(m.x)

    e = m.b - ab

    return e <= (m.tnac + m.s)
```

But when I try to call this function f in my objective function above, I get the message below for the expression `ab = f(m.x)` in the objective function:

```
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Objective Obj with index
    None: PyomoException: Cannot convert non-constant expression to bool. This
    error is usually caused by using an expression in a boolean context such
    as an if statement. For example,
        m.x = Var() if m.x <= 0:
        ...
would cause this exception.

ERROR: Constructing component 'Obj' from data=None failed: PyomoException:
    Cannot convert non-constant expression to bool. This error is usually
caused by using an expression in a boolean context such as an if
statement. For example,
        m.x = Var() if m.x <= 0:
        ...
would cause this exception.
```

Any idea on how to solve that would be very welcome.

Here is the complete code if needed. For this example I created the array macc with a function, but in reality it does not come from a function but from internal data.

```
import numpy as np
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import pyomo.core.kernel.piecewise_library.transforms as pyopiecewise

#Create macc
# logistic sigmoid function
def logistic(x, L=1, x_0=0, k=1):
    return L / (1 + np.exp(-k * (x - x_0)))


c = np.arange(401)
macc = 2000*logistic(c,L=0.5,x_0 = 60,k=0.02)
macc = macc -macc[0]

f = pyopiecewise.piecewise(c,macc,validate=False)

s0 = 800
b0 = 1000
tnac0 = 100

cp0 = 10
ab0 = 100

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

#Declare variable
model.x = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals, bounds=(5,395), initialize = cp0)

#Declare parameters
model.s = pyo.Param(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals,initialize=s0)
model.b = pyo.Param(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals,initialize=b0)
model.tnac = pyo.Param(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals,initialize=tnac0)

#Objective function
def objective_(m):
    ab = f(m.x)

    e = m.b - ab

    return (e * m.x)

model.Obj = pyo.Objective(rule=objective_)

#Constraints
def constraint1(m):

    ab = f(m.x)

    e = m.b - ab

    return e <= (m.tnac + m.s)

def constraint2(m): 

    ab = f(m.x)

    e = m.b - ab

    return e >= 1

def constraint3(m):

    ab = f(m.x)

    return ab >= 0


model.con1 = pyo.Constraint(rule = constraint1)
model.con2 = pyo.Constraint(rule = constraint2)
model.con3 = pyo.Constraint(rule = constraint3)
```

[And here is my objective function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTUjV.png)

Comment: Did you try to use an alternative variable (let's say ```model.y = pyo.Var()```)? you don't need to eval the piecewiese in the Var ```model.x``` just use the input and output args in the piecewise function.  ```f = piecewise(c, macc, input=model.x, output=model.y, ,validate=False)``` and then just use the ```model.y``` to use the evaluated piecewise function

Comment: This previous solution might be helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68626937/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-transformedpiecewiselinearfunctionnd-in-pyomo/68638931#68638931

You are mixing the `pyomo.environ` and `pyomo.kernel` libraries, which that post says is a no-go.  It also has some example references.  Not sure if that is your issue or not.  You might want to try to build a "toy" piecewise model (very simple one) with the `kernel` library and rebuild out from there as your model is pretty small/straightforward.

Comment: @pybegginer thank you for your suggestion, but I am not sure on how to implement that. Could you please expand a bit further? If you can show me where to write that in the model above, that would be much clearer. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RonB

As AirSquid commented, you're using the `kernel` and `environ` namespace. You should avoid this mixing, since several approach may not be compatible.

Instead of explicit evaluating the piecewised funtion using the `__call__()` (`f(model.x)`) method you can use the input, output args (in environ layer are called `xvar`, `yvar`) to output the evaluation in a defined variable.

Using the environ layer, piecewise function are available in [pyo.Piecewise](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Expressions.html#piecewise-linear-expressions)

```
import numpy as np
import pyomo.environ as pyo

#Create macc
# logistic sigmoid function
def logistic(x, L=1, x_0=0, k=1):
    return L / (1 + np.exp(-k * (x - x_0)))

c = np.linspace(0,400,400)
macc = 2000*logistic(c,L=0.5,x_0 = 60,k=0.02)
macc = macc -macc[0]

s0 = 800
b0 = 1000
tnac0 = 100

cp0 = 10
ab0 = 100

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

#Declare variable
model.x = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals, bounds=(5,395), initialize = cp0)
model.y = pyo.Var()
model.piecewise = pyo.Piecewise(model.y, model.x, pw_pts=list(c), f_rule=list(macc), pw_constr_type='EQ', pw_repn='DCC')

#Declare parameters
model.s = pyo.Param(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals,initialize=s0)
model.b = pyo.Param(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals,initialize=b0)
model.tnac = pyo.Param(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals,initialize=tnac0)


model.Obj = pyo.Objective(expr= model.b*model.x - model.y*model.x, sense=pyo.minimize)

model.con1 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.b - model.y <= model.tnac + model.s)
model.con2 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.b - model.y >= 1)
model.con3 = pyo.Constraint(expr= model.y >= 0)
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('ipopt')
solver.solve(model, tee=True)
```

In this modeling approach you don't have the problem of evaluate `model.piecewise(model.x)` in each equation (constraint or objective), instead you will just use `model.y` which is equivalent to evaluate.

Now, I don't know your problem, but that I guess your objective is not convex, which may be a further problem in the optimization. you can use `Gurobi` to solve such problems, but in this case, as `model.y` depends upon `model.x` and `model.x` is bounded, is going to the `model.x` upper bound in order to make objective as low as possible (since you don't declare any sense in the objective, I assume that you want to minimize). I think you should check your objective if it represents what you think.

Your objective function is doing something like this
[image: objective-function-w.r.t-xvar]

Comment: Sorry for that, I forgot one important correction to my array macc:
macc = macc -macc[0]

I corrected in the code above. The objective function becomes very different, always increasing. This makes the problem simpler, as I want to minimize, the solver just need to find the lowest value possible respecting the constraints.

Comment: Otherwise your approach seems to work, thanks for that. But I cannot be sure as I do not manage to solve the problem using ipopt solver. I get the message "Solver does not support SOS level 2 constraints". I am trying to find another free solver for a MINLP problem. (My real problem has binary variables).

Comment: The ```macc``` changes are not the problem, but certainly change the solution found. About the ```Solver does not support SOS level 2 constraints``` is not a big problem since SOS2 is just the piecewise representation used by default by ```pyomo``` you can change it to use ```ipopt```, just add the arg ```pw_repn='DCC'```, for instance, to use another approach. 
```model.piecewise = pyo.Piecewise(model.y, model.x, pw_pts=list(c), f_rule=list(macc), pw_constr_type='EQ', pw_repn='DCC')``` and that will solve the problem --> ```x=21.728, y=99.99, Obj=19,555.8``` This is the result using ipopt

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thanks a lot, I would have never find that alone.

Comment: Great. I hope you consider up-voting my answer or if it solve your problem and you think is the best approach, marked it as the answer with the check

Comment: Done, thanks. 
I still have the issue of the solver, my real problem is MINLP so does not use with ipopt. Looking for another one free of use.

Comment: Pyomo got a contrib solver called `mindtpy` [Link](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contributed_packages/mindtpy.html) to solve MINLP. `mindtpy` uses decomposition algorithms and MIP-NLP solvers to apply such approach. You might want to take a look at it

Comment: Thanks for that. I just tried with mindtpy but it gives me this error message 
"Numeric value `0.0` (<class 'float'>) is not in domain PositiveReals for Var piecewise.DCC_lambda[1,2]"

Comment: I'm not that sure, but I think that the problem is that your `model.x` vsr is bounded between (5,399) but is trying to evaluate it in 0. You might try to add some arg to the `Piecewise` such as `unbounded_domain_var=True` to tryna Ng to avoid that, but idk if it will work

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it did not work. I continue digging.
(Sorry was away for two weeks)